# USB cables combining shield and power ground conductor

Tags: usb, ground

I see a lot of USB "charging" cables on the market with cutaways showing two small data conductors, one large power conductor, and shield.

The implication is that power is conducted in the shield.

Is that really appropriate for USB cables?

Specifically USB, with its wide variety of devices. I realise that there are plenty of application-specific phantom power configurations where the devices are designed appropriately for that situation.

Comment: Are you asking about using them exclusively for power, or also for data?  ("with its wide variety of devices")

Comment: @endolith, cables used also for data.  If it's just charging I don't suppose there's much to interfere with.  Since the data connection is there, if the design is actually bad for data then you end up with this "mostly works" situation that fails at random (distinct from a charger cable with no data connection which obviously doesn't work so you stop using it right away).

Answer (score 2):

Considering that shielding the data wires is desirable to keep interference away, and considering that shielding is virtually always grounded, it should come as no surprise to find the ground conductor and the overall shield combined. In fact, in  most kinds of shielded cables, that is common practice.

There are rather complex "handshaking" protocols established for USB peripherals to negotiate for how much power they require from the host.  And for "dumb" hosts like simple chargers, Apple has a scheme for setting the D+ and D- pins at fixed voltages to indicate how much current is available.  For example...

[image: Apple current identification circuit]

Comment: Granted the shield is normally grounded, but people fuss a _lot_ about the specific topology of grounding, and I didn't think that shield ground was shorted to power ground arbitrarily all over the place.  Perhaps that _is_ standard practice in USB?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem when power is conducted through the shield. The shielding will most of the time have significantly higher maximum sustainable current than the very thin wire inside the today's average USB cable.

So using the shielding for 0 (black), a thicker wire for +5 (red) along the two data transmission thin wires is both a cost-efficient and technically-sound (appropriate) choice.

Comment: But only for power, not for data, correct?

Comment: Yes, only for power.

Answer (score 0):

Many high-current charging devices (both supplier and consumer) detect a ground connection on the shields on the two ends and interpret that to mean that the supply device can and should provide more than 500mA of usable current. These devices also use the shield connection as a second ground wire.

So is it appropriate to omit the normal ground wire and use the shield exclusively? It is debatable as to whether or not it is, but there are no popular devices that would operate incorrectly in such a case.

Comment: No device can detect the difference between a simple ground wire vs. a combined ground and shield. There is nothing to detect.  If you mean some connection between the ground pin #1 and the connector shell, please provide a reference to this information.

Comment: @RichardCrowley: I mean a connection between the shields on the opposite ends of the cable. One side grounds it and the other side detects this, presumably by trying to send current through the shield on their end. Cheap cables don't connect them, which is why they don't charge all devices properly.

Comment: Shield will always be grounded eventually.  You can't just check for DC current flow because that doesn't distinguish between grounded in a star configuration and re-grounded within the cable.

Comment: @sh1: Sure, but that's not what the devices are checking for. They're just looking to see if the shields are connected *somehow*.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, sorry that is impossible. Two disconnected devices can't detect when ground/shield/whatever is connected unless they have some **common reference**.  Certainly devices can tell when a USB connection is plugged in from the current between ground and power pins, however.

Comment: They will have the common reference on the ground pins as found in any functional USB cable.

Comment: Suppose you have a USB cable and you've already plugged it into the PC.  Even if shield and -ve power are separate in the cable, the PC will be shorting them together somewhere to sink any noise the shield picks up.  So when you connect a peripheral to the other end of that USB cable, how is it supposed to know that the short appears because of the cable and not because of the PC?

Comment: @sh1: If you're connected to a PC then you're expected to negotiate your current draw using older methods, up to a maximum of 500mA. If you don't and you draw too much current then the host is welcome to shut the port down entirely. The cable construction becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Typically they detect that they can draw more than 500 mA because of a short between the D+ and D- *data* lines.  I've never heard of anything checking the ground vs shield, if that's even possible.